# SharePoint Workflows to send a reminder mail after 24 hrs

Tags: workflow

[image]Can someone help to create a workflow as to send a mail after 24 hours from the SharePoint designer for a list?
I have tried the below steps and it does send across a mail but does not look at the time day specified. I want the ability to send across a mail after 24hrs of the request created as a reminder mail.

Below is the workflow I wrote in the SharePoint designer

Step: Step 1
If Current Item:Status equals Created
Pause for 0 days, 0 hours, 1440 minutes
Email User mail address

But for some reason, it does not look at the time or days added it just sends across the mail as soon as that is created.

Can someone help, please. thank you.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your workflow steps ?

Comment: So Basically I have a column called Status - which is a choice based column, I am looking to send across a mail to a few users if the request is pending from last 24 hrs... The email should only go if the status is left as Created and has not changed at all from last 24 hrs...

Answer (score 2):

Is your problem already solved? If not I'd say try this solution:

[image]

In this solution the workflow starts, then pauses for 24 hours. After 24 hours it checks if the status of the Current-Item:status is equal to Created, if this is true, it will send a reminder. If not it does nothing.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I like this logic much better. It only sends an email if the item is not acted upon. The initial solution checks if the item is acted upon NOW (on creation) and send the email later.

Answer (score 0):

Send email activity should be just below your pause activity.
So flow will be if condition is true then wait for 5 min and then send email.
As below :
[image]

In your screenshot , it is directly going to send email.Neither checking condition nor pause.

Comment: Okay, I moved that up but now I do not receive any mail at all?

Comment: that is because of your condition. You have to work on your condition. Given condition will has to be true in order to go to pause.

Comment: Looking at the List the workflow is Marked as Completed - But never received a mail.

Comment: Yes the condition is True - as we add a request in the column the default choice gets as created - so that is how we defined the condition that if the current item status is created - Then Pause for 5 Minutes and then send a mail across

Comment: Just add the logs and see what value status column is holding. Based on that you will come to know if condition is true or not. and one more log inside if condition to check its going inside if or not.